# Java Jsoup compare & replace arraylist

Tags: java, jsoup

I am really sorry for unclear explanation.

I need to compare two lists. List A contains [A], [B], [C] and List B contains [B], [C].
Now, i want to check in loop if list A contains letters / words from list B. If so, then remove those from list A.

Here is my code. Im using jsoup lib to parse table from url, but the url contains words that is needed to be removed. Like countries, ages etc...

I tried to make a new list which contained words that i want to be removed, but it didn't work. Help? :(

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("URL: ");
        String url = s.nextLine();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        /*Setting*/
        Document.OutputSettings settings = doc.outputSettings();
        settings.prettyPrint(false);
        settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
        settings.charset("ASCII");

        String modifiedFileHtmlStr = doc.html();

        List<String> tabList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table:eq(1)")) {
            System.getProperty("line.separator");
            for (Element row : doc.select("tr:gt(0)").not("td#t1_ckrs.td_fine")) {
                tabList.add(row.text());
            }
        }

        String row = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tabList.size(); i++) {
            row = tabList.get(i);
            System.out.println(row);

        }

    }
}
```

}

URL for the table: http://www.fidalservizi.it/risultati/Izmir_2014/Gara053.htm

Comment: Sure, it's possible. It's not clear what you're actually asking for, though.

Comment: It seems he/she wants to remove a set of "undesired words" from the table, but I am not sure

Comment: Leo, that was exactly what I meant.

Comment: What is the expected result? Only the names of the athletes?

Comment: Position, name and country abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your code snippet and comment, I think this might suffice your need.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fidalservizi.it/risultati/Izmir_2014/Gara053.htm").get();

Elements table = doc.select("tr:gt(0)").not("td#t1_ckrs.td_fine");
for (Element row : table) {

  if (isDataRow(row)) {
    System.out.print(" Pos :" + row.getElementById("t1_clas").text());
    System.out.print(" Name :" + row.getElementById("t1_atle").text());
    System.out.println(" Country " + row.getElementById("t1_soci").text());
  }
 }
}

private static boolean isDataRow(Element row){
  Elements elements = row.select("tr.due");
  elements.addAll(row.select("tr.uno"));
  return !elements.isEmpty() && !elements.text().equalsIgnoreCase("");
}
```

This prints

```
Pos :1 Name :CHEVAUX Christophe Country  FRA FRANCE
Pos :  Name :European Champion Country  
Pos :2 Name :VAN DER PUTTEN Marijn Country  NED NETHERLANDS
Pos :3 Name :BAGHIROV Faig Country  AZE AZERBAIJAN
Pos :4 Name :DIEGO Miguel Angel Country  ESP SPAIN
Pos :5 Name :CAMBRIA Giuseppe Country  ITA ITALY
Pos :6 Name :YILMAZ Ozgur Country  TUR TURKEY
Pos :7 Name :MAFTEI Nelu Vasilica Country  ROU ROMANIA
```